# Adding Facebook/Tweet button to Fancybox2

Tags: php, facebook, fancybox

Following this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmLWf/)

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
beforeShow: function () {
    if (this.title) {
        // New line
        this.title += '<br />';

        // Add tweet button
        this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

        // Add FaceBook like button
        this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
    }
},
afterShow: function () {
    // Render tweet button
    twttr.widgets.load();
},
helpers: {
    title: {
        type: 'inside'
    }, //<-- add a comma to separate the following option
    buttons: {} //<-- add this for buttons
},
closeBtn: false, // you will use the buttons now
arrows: false
});
```

I can't seem to get the Facebook/Tweet buttons to work, they aren't showing up at all.

As an added wrinkle, the fancybox code is being pulled from a php file, which might explain why it's not working but I'm still unsure how to fix it.

Will take any suggestions, would like to be able to make it so that individual photos can easily be shared on Facebook specifically.

[my site](http://www.needyounowequine.com/availablehorses.php) for why 
(don't judge! only a few hours of work have gone into it so far, lol) 
only the newest horses have the fancybox scripting, I'm in the process of building while we work :S.

Comment: Your JS fiddle works just fine. I can see the buttons.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G5TC3/